# PHP: Unable to see variables from POST of a form

Tags: php, variables, post

I have a very basic form with two fields (a login form). The variables are posted to a script (shown below), however I am unable to see any posted vars. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, can somebody help me out?

```
<?php
    add_page_content();
    function add_page_content() {
    $error = true;
    echo '      <div id="page_content">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <div id="login_form">
            '
        . ($error ? '<p class="text_red">Wrong username and/or password.</p>' : '') . '
            <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <div id="login_fields">
                    <div>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input id="admin_user_input" type="text" name="username" ' . ($error ? ('value="' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]) . '"') : '') . '>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input id="admin_pass_input" type="password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input id="login_submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
            ' . 'username: ' . $_POST["username"] . '
        </div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

EDIT: Ops, I have no idea what happened, I lost half of my post... here I go retyping it:

If I trace the post vars of the request using httpfox addon, here is what I get:
-let's assume I will fill "user" into the username field, "pass" into password.
RAW:

```
username=user
password=pass
submit=Go
```

PRETTY:

```
Parameter         Value
username          userpassword
```

Thanks a lot for feedback!

Comment: You have failed to associate your `label` elements with their `inputs`. Either put the `input` inside the `label` or set `for="id_of_input"` on the `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

PHP won't parse plain text submissions. Take it out, so the default (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) is used instead.

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. They are **not reliably interpretable by computer**, as the format is ambiguous (for example, there is no way to distinguish a literal newline in a value from the newline at the end of the value).

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text/plain-encoding-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

remove enctype (by default application/x-www-form-urlencoded )